# What does ∀id1 id2 : id, {id1 = id2} + {id1 ≠ id2} mean?

Tags: coq, imperative-languages

I'm reading Software Foundations book and in Imp.v file, there is this definition of a theorem eq_id_dec as follows:

```
Theorem eq_id_dec : forall id1 id2 : id, {id1 = id2} + {id1 <> id2}.
Proof.
   intros id1 id2.
   destruct id1 as [n1]. destruct id2 as [n2].
   destruct (eq_nat_dec n1 n2) as [Heq | Hneq].
   Case "n1 = n2".
     left. rewrite Heq. reflexivity.
   Case "n1 <> n2".
     right. intros contra. inversion contra. apply Hneq. apply H0.
Defined.
```

Does this theorem mean that for any id1 and id2 of type id, both id1=id2 and id1!=id2 cannot happen? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not preclude the case that both the equality and the inequality are true at the same time (though in practice it is the case here).

The type `sumbool A B`, of notation `{A} + {B}`, characterizes a decision procedure that will prove either `A` or `B`.

So this `eq_id_dec` is a term that will take two `id`s as input, and either return a proof that they are equal, or a proof that they are distinct.

More about sumbool here: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Bool.Sumbool.html

Comment: So, if I have to call this function, i have to pass in a value of type id. Id is Id: nat -> id. How would i do that. I do Eval Compute in (eq_id_dec (id 4) (id 5)). and it fails

Comment: Eval compute in (eq_id_dec (Id 4) (Id 5)).

Answer (score -1):

For all id1 and id2, id1 = id2 or id1 does not equal id2.

Pretty straightforward - either it equals id2 or it does not, which will by definition always be true - so it is true for all id1/id2.

Comment: Except that in an intuitionistic framework like Coq, `P \/ ~P` is not necessarily true (you can add excluded middle as an axiom). You have to prove that the equality is decidable (hence the `dec` in the name of the theorem) in the type of `id1` and `id2`.